# Android layout for different screen sizes

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent

I am new to android and i am trying to create a single layout for different screen size.Is it possible or am i want to create different layout for different screens

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course you can only provide the layout in `res/layout`, but it might look ugly on other screen sizes, even though (or because) Android tries to scale it.

It is *not possible* to define layouts for different reolutions *in a single file*. It's just possible to design the layout to be dynamic so Android can adjust it to the given resolution as good as possible.